# hive query - date substraction issue

Tags: hive

I am just trying to get last to last Monday's date when input date is Tuesday in HIVE

When the input date is 15th Nov-2016 then it is showing last to last Monday's date correctly. i.e. 31st Oct-2016 using the below query

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-11-15','yy-MM-dd')-15*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

But when the input date is 15th Mar-2016 then it is not showing last to last Monday's date correctly. In this case it is showing 28th Feb-2016 using the below query

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-03-15','yy-MM-dd')-15*60*60*24, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Can anyone suggest why it is behaving like this

Comment: I'm getting the right result: `2016-02-29` with your second query in Hive 1.2.1000 (HDP). Which Hive version are you using?

Comment: Our version is 1.1.0

Comment: Strange... In this Hue editor (http://demo.gethue.com/beeswax/#query) I'm getting the right result as well.